# ORACLE Group By & Duplicates

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct

I come from a MySQL background and am having problems with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT agenda.idagenda AS "ID_SERVICE", agenda.name AS "ID_SERVICE_NAME", specialities.id AS "ID_DEPARTMENT", specialities.name AS "ID_DEPARTMENT_NAME", 
                supervisor.clients_waiting AS "CWaiting",
                (CASE WHEN supervisor.clients_resent_waiting_area IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE supervisor.clients_resent_waiting_area END) AS "CWaiting_Resent_Area",
                supervisor.clients_attending AS "CAttending",
                supervisor.clients_attended  AS "CAttended",
                (SELECT MAX(ROUND((SYSDATE-core.supervisor_time_data.time_attending)*86400)) FROM dual) AS "MTA",
                (SELECT MAX(ROUND((SYSDATE-core.supervisor_time_data.time_waiting)*86400)) FROM dual) AS "MTE",
                (SELECT SUM(SYSDATE-supervisor_time_data.time_attending)*86400 FROM dual)/(SELECT supervisor.clients_attending FROM dual) AS "TMA", 
                (SELECT SUM(SYSDATE-supervisor_time_data.time_waiting)*86400 FROM dual)/(SELECT supervisor.clients_waiting FROM dual) AS "TME", 
                supervisor.tme_accumulated AS "TME_ACCUMULATED", 
                supervisor.tma_accumulated AS "TMA_ACCUMULATED", 
                (CASE WHEN agenda.alarm_cee IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE agenda.alarm_cee END) AS "ALARM_CEE",
                (CASE WHEN agenda.alarm_mte IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE agenda.alarm_mte END) AS "ALARM_MTE",
                (CASE WHEN agenda.alarm_mta IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE agenda.alarm_mta END) AS "ALARM_MTA",
                (CASE WHEN agenda.alarm_tme IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE agenda.alarm_tme END) AS "ALARM_TME"
                FROM CORE.supervisor 
                LEFT JOIN CORE.supervisor_time_data ON supervisor_time_data.id_service = supervisor.id_service 
                LEFT JOIN CORE.agenda ON supervisor.id_service = agenda.id 
                LEFT JOIN CORE.specialities ON agenda.idspeciality = specialities.id 

            WHERE supervisor.booked_or_sequential = 1

            GROUP BY agenda.idagenda, agenda.name, supervisor.id_service, specialities.id, specialities.name, supervisor.clients_waiting, supervisor.clients_resent_waiting_area, 
            supervisor.clients_attending, supervisor.clients_attended,
            supervisor_time_data.time_attending, supervisor_time_data.time_waiting, 
            supervisor.tme_accumulated, supervisor.tma_accumulated, agenda.alarm_cee, agenda.alarm_mte,agenda.alarm_mta,agenda.alarm_tme;
```

It should return two records, but instead it's returning four. ID_SERIVE is returning 3 records with the same value.

```
"ID_SERVICE"    "ID_SERVICE_NAME"   "ID_DEPARTMENT" "ID_DEPARTMENT_NAME"    "CWaiting"  "CWaiting_Resent_Area"  "CAttending"    "CAttended" "MTA"   "MTE"   "TMA"   "TME"   "TME_ACCUMULATED"   "TMA_ACCUMULATED"   "ALARM_CEE" "ALARM_MTE" "ALARM_MTA" "ALARM_TME"
"DR"    "DR"    1   "SECUENCIALES"  1   0   1   1   5504        5504        21  109 0   0   0   0
"DR"    "DR"    1   "SECUENCIALES"  1   0   1   1       1590            1590.000000000000000000000000000000000002   21  109 0   0   0   0
"DR"    "DR"    1   "SECUENCIALES"  1   0   1   1                   21  109 0   0   0   0
"TRAU"  "TRAU"  1   "SECUENCIALES"  1   0   0   0       1567        1567.000000000000000000000000000000000002   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You're grouping by values that are different - the `id_servie`is the same but the others are not. If it only showed one row for each service, which MTA value, for example, should it have? You can group by some columns and have aggregates (sum, min, max etc.) on the others but it isn't clear what you really want. It looks like you just have too much in the `group by` clause. Do you want the max MTA value for each service? (And what's with all the subselects from dual?)

Comment: The MTA value should be MAX. In Oracle the group by clause needs to include all SELECTS. If I ommit one of them I get the error "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: The `group by` needs to include all select-list items that are not aggregate functions, which is an important distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be including all the columns you're interesting in the `group by`, and not aggregating properly; possibly you've got to this point by trial and error as you've tried to resolve errors from columns not being grouped. You don't need the sub-selects in all the column clauses.

Untested as we don't have your tables or raw data but it looks like you want something like:

```
SELECT agenda.idagenda AS "ID_SERVICE",
  agenda.name AS "ID_SERVICE_NAME",
  specialities.id AS "ID_DEPARTMENT",
  specialities.name AS "ID_DEPARTMENT_NAME", 
  supervisor.clients_waiting AS "CWaiting",
  NVL(supervisor.clients_resent_waiting_area, 0) AS "CWaiting_Resent_Area",
  supervisor.clients_attending AS "CAttending",
  supervisor.clients_attended  AS "CAttended",
  MAX(ROUND((SYSDATE - supervisor_time_data.time_attending)*86400)) AS "MTA",
  MAX(ROUND((SYSDATE - supervisor_time_data.time_waiting)*86400)) AS "MTE",
  SUM(SYSDATE - supervisor_time_data.time_attending)*86400
    / supervisor.clients_attending AS "TMA", 
  SUM(SYSDATE - supervisor_time_data.time_waiting)*86400
    / supervisor.clients_waiting AS "TME", 
  supervisor.tme_accumulated AS "TME_ACCUMULATED", 
  supervisor.tma_accumulated AS "TMA_ACCUMULATED", 
  NVL(agenda.alarm_cee, 0) AS "ALARM_CEE",
  NVL(agenda.alarm_mte, 0) AS "ALARM_MTE",
  NVL(agenda.alarm_mta, 0) AS "ALARM_MTA",
  NVL(agenda.alarm_tme, 0) AS "ALARM_TME"
FROM CORE.supervisor 
LEFT JOIN CORE.supervisor_time_data
  ON supervisor_time_data.id_service = supervisor.id_service 
LEFT JOIN CORE.agenda ON supervisor.id_service = agenda.id 
LEFT JOIN CORE.specialities ON agenda.idspeciality = specialities.id 
WHERE supervisor.booked_or_sequential = 1
GROUP BY agenda.idagenda, agenda.name, supervisor.id_service, specialities.id,
  specialities.name, supervisor.clients_waiting,
  supervisor.clients_resent_waiting_area, supervisor.clients_attending,
  supervisor.clients_attended, supervisor.tme_accumulated,
  supervisor.tma_accumulated, agenda.alarm_cee,
  agenda.alarm_mte,agenda.alarm_mta,agenda.alarm_tme;
```

So specifically, `supervisor_time_data.time_waiting` and `supervisor_time_data.time_attending` don't need to be in the `group by` as they are used in aggregate.

I've replaced your `case` checks with `nvl` just because it's shorter; case is fine though if you prefer that.

Comment: Same error, ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 3. I didn't know about nvl, thanks

Comment: @Anton - I'd pulled the wrong column out of the group-by; cut-and-paste error, sorry. I don't get an error with this code now.